# What is causing React to re-render this component infinitely?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop

I'm in the process of creating a login/signup component for an application I'm building. I would like the component to read the address bar and set itself to login mode or signup mode depending on if the domain is followed by a "/login" or "/signup" respectively.

For a reason unknown to me, the component is re-rendering infinitely when the state change function is called within the if block. It doesn't do this if I remove the else block from the if statement and attempt to access the page with "http://localhost:3000/signup"

Any and all advice is appreciated, as well as any possible solutions.

Register component: https://pastebin.com/pE2t5gdw

```
import React, {
  Fragment,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
} from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../../shared/context/AuthContext";
 
import Card from "../../shared/components/UIElements/Card";
 
import "./Register.css";
 
const Register = () => {
  const [isLoginMode, setIsLoginMode] = useState(false);            // state creation
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const registerSubmitHandler = () => {
    auth.login();
  };
 
  if (window.location.pathname.toString() === "/login") {           // attempt to determine if we should present signup or login
    setIsLoginMode(true);
  } else {
    setIsLoginMode(false);
  }
 
  return (
    <Card className="authentication">
      <h1>{!isLoginMode ? "signup mode" : "login mode"}</h1>        // result of login or signup mode
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <button onClick={registerSubmitHandler}>Register</button>
        <button onClick={setIsLoginMode(!isLoginMode)}>Switch mode</button>   // supposed to change modes within the component
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};
 
export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about react [lifecycles](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp), especially with hooks now.

Import the `useEffect` hook from React and place your if block into it like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window.location.pathname.toString() === "/login") setIsLoginMode(true);
        else setIsLoginMode(false);
    } , [])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I managed to rework the change login mode button and that now works too. I'll take a look at that react lifecycles reading.

Comment: @shan_pritc Glad I could help.